# How to add an array but also keep each element of the array within a certain range?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am working with RL and my agent is giving me an array (1 X 6) as action i.e. the joint angles of the robot which are in the range from (-pi, pi).

Now, I am getting these actions into my step function in the environment and I calculate my action as `action = current_joint_value + (0.02*(joint angle chosen by the agent))`. The value 0.02 is a scaling value to keep a continuity to the movement of the robot.

So the above setting works perfectly but after a certain no of steps in the episode I see that the action values goes beyond the range (-pi, pi) because the of the additon of the joint values.

I somehow want to incorporate this setting i.e. `action = current_joint_value + (0.02*(joint angle chosen by the agent))` but with also a constraint that each value in the array should be within the range (-pi, pi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
action = np.clip(current_joint_value + (0.02*(joint angle chosen by the agent)), -np.pi, np.pi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
action=where(action > pi,pi,action)
action=where(action < -pi,-pi,action)
```

Comment: Why should they try this? Provide some context and explanation for your answer to make it useful.